# Question X Doubt

Tags: word-choice

What's the correct form to ask someone if they understood what has been said:

Do you have any question or Do you have any doubt?

Comment: It really depends on what you just told them!  If you just gave them a very technically-involved explanation of a procedure, you should ask them, "Do you have any questions?"  If, on the other hand, you just presented them with an unusual way of doing things that has not been tried before, your question should be along the lines of "Do you have any doubts about whether this new procedure would work?"

Comment: I have a Chilean friend (not a native English speaker) who says "Do you have any doubts?" quite often.  When he uses the phrase, it's generally in more casual conversation.  In those cases, I would recommend something similar to "Did that make sense?" or "Was that clear?"  I agree with rhetorician in the examples that he provided.  In a lecture-type scenario, the question "Are there any questions?" is often used.

Answer (score 0):

A few common forms are:

1. "Does that make sense?"

   - This is probably the most common and is used in everday conversation.
2. "Do you have any questions?"

   - This is most commonly used by someone who is teaching or giving a presentation.

Most native English speakers would almost never say "Do you have any doubts?". And a native English speaker would probably be confused if you said that.